# Right Kan extension along a diagonal functor.

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Denote $\newcommand{\simpcat}{\boldsymbol\Delta} \simpcat$ the simplex category (category of finite ordinals with non decreasing maps). The diagonal functor $\delta \colon \simpcat \to \simpcat\times\simpcat$ induces a functor
$$ \newcommand{\psh}{\widehat}
\delta^\ast \colon \psh{\simpcat \times \simpcat} \to \psh\simpcat $$
mapping a bisimplicial set $K$ to the simplicial set $\newcommand{\ordinal}[1]{[#1]} \ordinal n \mapsto K_{n,n}$.

Because $\newcommand{\Set}{\mathsf{Set}}\Set$ is complete, $\delta^\ast$ has a right adjoint, namely the right Kan extension functor along $\newcommand{\op}[1]{#1^\text{op}}\op\delta$. Now, the paper I'm reading states that this right adjoint $\delta_\ast$ maps any simplicial set $X$ to the bisimplicial set
$$ (\ordinal m ,\ordinal n) \mapsto \hom_{\psh{\simpcat}}(\Delta[m]\times\Delta[n],X) $$
where $\Delta[-]$ is the Yoneda embedding $\simpcat \hookrightarrow \psh{\simpcat}$.

I'm having trouble deriving this explicit form from the general form of right Kan extensions. Here is what I've done so far :
$$ \begin{aligned}
(\delta_\ast X)_{m,n} &= \lim_{\left( (\ordinal m, \ordinal n) \downarrow\op\delta \right)} X \\
&= \lim_{\left( (\ordinal m, \ordinal n) \downarrow\op\delta \right)} \hom_{\psh{\simpcat}}(\Delta[-],X) \\
&= \hom_{\psh{\simpcat}}\left(\operatorname*{colim}_{\left( (\ordinal m, \ordinal n) \downarrow\op\delta \right)}\Delta[-],X\right) \\
\end{aligned} $$
But I can't manage to show that $\operatorname*{colim}_{\left( (\ordinal m, \ordinal n) \downarrow\op\delta \right)}\Delta[-]$ is actually $\Delta[m] \times \Delta[n]$. The only cocone over the diagram $\Delta[-] \colon \left( (\ordinal m, \ordinal n) \downarrow\op\delta \right) \to \psh{\simpcat}$ I can imagine is the *tautological* one : for any object $(f,g)$ of $\left( (\ordinal m, \ordinal n) \downarrow\op\delta \right)$ (with $f \colon \ordinal k \to \ordinal m$ and $g \colon \ordinal k \to \ordinal n$), denote $\mu_{(f,g)}$ the morphism $\Delta[k] \to \Delta[m] \times \Delta[n]$ corresponding under Yoneda's lemma to the $k$-simplices $(f,g)$ of $\Delta[m] \times \Delta[n]$. But I don't see why this cocone is universal (actually, I'm not even sure it is a cocone...).

Any hint ?

Comment: Why go to the trouble of using the general formula? You just have to check that the given formula does actually define a right adjoint, and that is quite straightforward. More generally, you might like to show that for any functor $f : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, $f_* : [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] \to [\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ can be defined by $f_* X (d) = [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](\mathcal{D}(f -, d), X)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin My idea was : what if I were writing the paper and did not have the answer ? By the general theory of Kan extensions, I would know that there is a right adjoint and would naturally want to simplify the general formula to my particular case.

Comment: Then you should learn either the weighted limit or the end version of the right Kan extension formula. The claim is then a straightforward application of the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: @ZhenLin I will look into this. Thank you for the leads.

Comment: ... actually, you can just apply the Yoneda lemma in this case: $$f_* X (d) \cong [\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](\mathcal{D}(-, d), f_* X) \cong [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](\mathcal{D}(f -, d), X)$$

Comment: @ZhenLin I actually saw that ealier today, thanks.